# Polish cartoon with an green zombie

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have memories of an cartoon from Poland that i watched when i was young, it was made in CGI and there is an green zombie with an sweater, he talks with an Mickey Mouse-like voice has an pet teddy bear and says
"dzień dobry"

But also this character that i talking about look like this

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [Włatcy móch](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C5%82atcy_m%C3%B3ch) ([Eng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C5%82atcy_m%C3%B3ch)). The character in question is Czesio.

[image]

Polish Wikipedia:

> Głównymi bohaterami serialu są czterej ośmiolatkowie – uczniowie klasy II b Szkoły Podstawowej im. Batalionu Zośka – Czesio, Maślana, Anusiak i Konieczko oraz ich nauczycielka – Pani Frał. Akcja serialu dzieje się głównie we Wrocławiu, chociaż poszczególne odcinki rozgrywały się także w Warszawie, Kaliningradzie, Suwałkach oraz w Jałcie. Odcinki Włatców móch celowo zawierają wiele błędów ortograficznych, podobnie jak sam tytuł produkcji. Bohaterowie w dialogach często posługują się wulgaryzmami. Jednak wyprodukowano również wersję ocenzurowaną z usuniętymi wulgaryzmami i wymazanymi bardziej drastycznymi scenami. Tytuł serialu nawiązuje do tytułu powieści Władca much angielskiego pisarza Williama Goldinga.

English Wikipedia:

> Włatcy móch (Polish pronunciation: [ˈvwatsˑɨ mux]) (English: The Lordz o' Flys) is a Polish adult animated comedy series, which had been on the Polish TV channel TV4 between November 2006 and December 2011. The title is a misspelled version of "Władcy much" meaning "The Lords of Flies" and derives from William Golding's novel Lord of the Flies. The plot of the story revolves around four 8-year-old boys in the second grade of elementary school: Anusiak, Konieczko, Maślana and Czesio. The show has a total of 127 regular and 2 special episodes. There is also a feature movie. The comedy won the 2008 Świry Award [pl] in category "TV Series".